# Can't install Android ADT in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, installation

Help! With Windows 7, Galileo, Eclipse 3.5.2: every time I click Finish when installing ADT I get the error 'Install has encountered a problem - an error occurred while uninstalling'. Details:

```
String index out of range:0 
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_21
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_GB
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
```

Error

```
Sat Aug 21 15:40:46 BST 2010
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.phases.Uninstall, operand=[R]org.apache.commons.lang 2.3.0.v200803061910 --> [R]org.apache.commons.lang 2.3.0.v201005080501, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.UninstallBundleAction).
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're installing it an not uninstall it or something? I would try downloading a fresh copy of eclipse and try installing it onto that

Answer (score 0):

It's happened to me as well, though I'm on Linux, not Windows (but it was also Eclipse 3.5.2). I uninstalled Eclipse then reinstalled it and the first thing I then installed was Android SDK. It now works well.

Comment: Thanks. That's the order of events I already followed, but I'll try a reinstall of Eclipse.