# Can't install the android adt in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Actually I downloaded the plugin ADT also, but I am still getting errors like this:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>     Software being installed: Android Hierarchy Viewer 22.6.0.v201403010043-1049357 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.group 22.6.0.v201403010043-1049357)
>     Missing requirement: Android Hierarchy Viewer 22.6.0.v201403010043-1049357 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.group 22.6.0.v201403010043-1049357) requires 'org.eclipse.ui 3.7.0' but it could not be found

What does this mean?

I tried previous answers that are in posted in this site but no use.
Please help me to overcome this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: duplicate question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540807/cant-install-android-adt-in-eclipse

Comment: I think there is a lot of difference between that error and mine error, and there is no particular answer for that question also.So if you can please help me.

Comment: Sounds like a possible version mismatch to me.  Your error says that `Android Hierarchy Viewer 22.6.0.v201403010043-1049357` requires `'org.eclipse.ui 3.7.0'`, which it can't find.  

Which version of Eclipse do you have?  In particular, is it Eclipse 3.7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

download this jar from the below url and put into the plugins folder under your eclipse and then restart your eclipse then try again . Hope it worke.

http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.7/org.eclipse/ui/3.7.0

Comment: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ put this url under the Eclipse Installation and update your eclipse hope it will worke..

Comment: At last I got the solution for this problem.Actually I followed tutorials in which they downloaded old version of eclipse according to the old tutorials.Now I tried newest version of eclipse and its done,new software installed

Answer (score 0):

Try re-installing eclipse again

Answer (score 0):

Download Eclipse Indigo.  I was on Helios, then went up to Kepler, but neither worked.  It seems you have to have version 3.7 (Indigo) for this to work.

https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/indigo/sr2